# Loading LabelEncoder using pickle : Previously unseen values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

**Here i create the Label Encoder Method:**
'''

```
def encoder(sc_train,sc_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    cols = sc_train.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
    # extract categorical attributes from both training and test sets
    cat_train = sc_train.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
    cat_test = sc_test.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()

    # encode the categorical attributes
    train_cat = cat_train.apply(le.fit_transform)
    test_cat = cat_test.apply(le.fit_transform)

    encs_train = pd.DataFrame(train_cat,columns=cols)
    encs_test = pd.DataFrame(train_cat, columns=cols)

    pickle_filename = open("encoder2.pkl","wb")
    pickle.dump(le, pickle_filename)
    pickle_filename.close()
    return encs_train,encs_test
```

**Then I try to load my LabelEncoder Model using pickle:**

```
file = open("encoder2.pkl","rb")
encoder = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

data2 = {'flag': ['SF','SF','S0','REJ']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=['flag'])
X = encoder.transform(df2['flag'])
print(X)
```

**Error: ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'SF' **

Note: that 'SF' is a value that is in the training set when i trained the labelencoder and it is not unseen value